# Definition of an exterior algebra 'generated by' certain elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I am trying to make sense of the following, in Proposition 1.5 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf).

> Let $E$ be the exterior algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with a generator $x_i\in E_{2^i}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

I understand the definition on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Formal_definitions_and_algebraic_properties) of the exterior algebra of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, and therefore of the exterior algebra of a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. But how does this relate to $E$ above? So far as I can tell, $E_n$ is not defined anywhere, so I cannot make sense of $E_{2^i}$ either.

How can I understand exactly what $E$ is?

Also, just before this, there is a reference to 'the exterior algebra $$\mathbb{F}_2[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/(x_0^2,\ldots,x_n^2).$$

What $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space is this the exterior algebra of? I think I have completely misunderstood this.

Comment: The paper concerns graded algebras. $E_{2^i}$ means the degree-$2^i$ piece, so that expression is saying that $x_i$ is being given degree $2^i$. The second exterior algebra is the exterior algebra of the free vector space on $x_0, \dots x_n$. Note that over $\mathbb{F}_2$ commuting is the same thing as anticommuting.

Comment: So first of all taking the exterior algebra of the free $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space on $\{x_i:i\geq 0\}$, setting $E_n$ to be the degree $n$ piece, and then $E$ is $\oplus_{i}E_{2^i}$? I'm not too confident that I understood you correctly. Does 'degree $k$' mean linear combinations of terms of the form $x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_k$?

Comment: Yes, we take the exterior algebra of the free $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space on $\{ x_i \}$, but then we give this exterior algebra a grading where $x_i$ is in degree $2^i$. This doesn't mean it's the only element in that degree, it's just assigned that degree and then e.g. $x_i \wedge x_j$ has degree $2^i + 2^j$ and so forth.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I don't quite follow the 'giving it a new grading' bit. If $E$ is the direct sum of the $E_{2^i}$ i.e. including just those of degree $2^i$ then isn't this strictly contained with the exterior algebra, rather than giving it a new grading?

Comment: No, $E$ is the direct sum $\bigoplus E_i$. It is defined so that it is *generated by* elements $x_i \in E_{2^i}$ of degree $2^i$ but it contains elements of every degree, e.g. $x_0 \wedge x_1$ has degree $3$, $x_0 \wedge x_2$ has degree $5$, etc. etc.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So we start with the exterior algebra of $\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{F}_2$, choose elements $x_i$ of degree $2^i$ for each $i$ and then..? I can see how the exterior algebra is generated by the set of all $y_1\wedge\cdots\wedge y_{2^i}$, $i\geq 0$ but the change of grading thing is confusing me a lot. Also I was under the impression that there were no choices involved in this construction

Comment: As an algebra, it is the exterior algebra on countably many generators $x_i$, which is to say that it's the exterior algebra on the free vector space spanned by the $x_i$ Normally the exterior algebra has a grading where each generator is in degree $1$. This construction considers an unusual grading where $x_i$ is in degree $2^i$, and then extended by multiplicativity. I do not know how to be clearer about the construction than this, and I don't know what you mean by "choices."